# Using tf.batch_scatter_add in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm looking for a way to use [tf.scatter_add](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scatter_add) with Keras batches. 
Shape of outputs: `(?, 1000)` and shapes of indices and updates are `(?, 100)` each.

Try1: Using Keras tensors

```
vals = tf.scatter_add(outputs, indices, updates)
```

This throws an error:

> 'Tensor' object has no attribute '_lazy_read'

Try2: Tried using k.variable which should be updatable

```
vals = K.variable(outputs)
vals = tf.scatter_add(vals, inputs[1], inputs[2])
```

> ValueError: initial_value must have a shape specified: 
>       Tensor("scatter_add_43/zeros_like:0", shape=(?, 1000), dtype=float32))

Any clues? `Scatter_add` and `batch_scatter_add` result in the same errors. Will I need to write a custom layer for this? Seems like even that will run into one of the above errors.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a Layer for this. You can use `tf.tensor_scatter_add` to update **Tensors** directly or `scatter_nd_add` (method from `tf.Variable`) to update **Variables**.

References:

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tensor_scatter_add
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable#scatter_nd_add

Unfortunately, Tensorflow API does not have a `tf.batched_scatter_nd_add` yet. So we have to try mimic this behaviour. Both methods work with individual or slices. In order to work with batches, we need to transform the indices to the expected multi-dimensional expected.

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()

batch_size = 2
vocab_size = 6
seq_len = 3

predictions = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([batch_size, vocab_size], dtype=tf.float32))

indices = tf.constant([[0, 2, 4], [1, 3, 5]], dtype=tf.int32)
updates = tf.ones([batch_size, seq_len], dtype=tf.float32)

batched_indices = [[i, j.numpy()] for i, indexes in enumerate(indices) for j in indexes]
batched_updates = tf.reshape(updates, [-1])  # flatten

predictions.scatter_nd_add(indices=batched_indices, updates=batched_updates)

print(predictions)
```

Output:

```
<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(2, 6) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1.]], dtype=float32)>
```